# R connect to MySQL server with enable-cleartext-plugin option

Tags: mysql, r

I'm trying to connect to remote MySQL server via TCP/IP.
Server requires mysql-clear-password enabled.
I use RMySQL library on Kubuntu 16.04 to connect to server, but there is no option other than to configure odbc.ini file to pass the plugin trigger. When running the code I get error

> Failed to connect to database: Error: Plugin mysql_clear_password
>   could not be loaded

Is there a way to pass this trigger with RMySQL?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by getting new version of MySQL ODBC connector from official site https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/

Then /etc/odbc.ini file is configured as follows

```
[connection]
Driver                  = /usr/lib/odbc/libmyodbc5a.so
Database                = [db]
Server                  = [server]
Port                    = [port]
User                    = [user]
Password                = [pw]
SSLMODE                 = REQUIRED
ENABLE_CLEARTEXT_PLUGIN = 1
sslca                   = [location]
```

In my case ssl certificate was also required